# Regex Match URLS but Not Images

Tags: regex, preg-match

```
/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/
```

I'm using the above to search through HTML code that contains text, image urls, and regular urls. I want to modify the above so that it only matches strings that are NOT images. I've searched for this quite a bit but came up dry. I was trying to use "negative lookahead matching" to ignore links that end in jpg|png|gif but I haven't had any success with that.

For example:

```
http://www.google.com <- valid match

www.example.com/image.jpg <-should not match
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the regex you tried using with the negative lookahead?

Comment: it's worth noting that negative lookaheads are very easy to write incorrectly.

Comment: /(https?:\/\/\S+\.(!?:jpg|png|gif))\s+/

Comment: _“I want to modify the above so that it only matches strings that are NOT images.”_ – strings never “are” images. Are you talking about HTML code here, where you don’t want to match URLs in the `src` attribute of image elements? Otherwise you could only _guess_ whether or not an URL would deliver image content or something else – `http://example.com/foo.html` could easily deliver an image if the operator of that domain would chose to do so, and the other way around `http://example.com/image.jpg` could as well deliver HTML, or something completely different.

Comment: My mistake. Yes this is HTML code. The issue is <img src="url here">. The "url here" is getting matched and I don't want it to. I figured if the url does not contain jpg|png|gif I should be okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the negative lookahead doesn't seem to be very healthy :)

Try something like this:

```
https?://(?![^" ]*(?:jpg|png|gif))[^" ]+
         ^-----------------------^
```

The lookahead has the format `(?! ... )` and I have put `[^" ]*` before the image extensions to allow any number of characters between the `https?//` part to the extension. You can then proceed to match the rest of the string with `[^" ]` that you are already using.

Also, you apply this regex like this:

```
preg_match('~https?://(?![^" ]*(?:jpg|png|gif))[^" ]+~', $text, $match);
```

so that you don't have a lot to escape with the backslashes.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vH3bB2).

Comment: Found one issue...If the url is like so http://www.google.com<br> it is grabbing the <br> as part of the url...is there any easy fix?

Comment: @user1647347 Yup, put `<>` in the negated classes so that all `[^" ]` become `[^" <>]`.